# Price Comparison Sheet, highlighting cheapest

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I have created a Google Sheet for purchasing some new products and I'd like to highlight which cell on each row is the cheapest. I know how to do this with several Conditional Formatting rules (one for each row), but is it possible to have one rule for the entire range?

[image]

Column G has the formula `=MIN(B2:E2)` for each row so that I can see each cheapest price and total them up at the bottom of the column. The way I would normally do this is select each cell in G and put a Conditional Formatting for range B2:E2 with custom formula =G2 (formatting accordingly).

Can this be done with a single rule applied to the whole range? I've tried what I have found by Googling, but it either highlights all cells in the column or range and not the single cell that matches G for each row.

Comment: Can you please post what you've tried so far?

Comment: @badermart player0 seems to have answered the question successfully. So I am holding back on updating (I was in the middle of it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Conditional Formatting, select the range B2:E2

then choose 'Value is equal to'

and put in

```
=$G2
```

The formula is automatically adjusted for each cell by relative addressing.

[image]

**EDIT**

To stop it highlighting blank rows, you would need

```
=and(B2=$G2,B2<>"")
```

as a custom formula.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer, and that is why I accepted it. I've since discovered that if applied to a bunch of empty rows that I haven't filled in yet, it colours them in too. So I am a little torn between the 2 answers I have received, but have stuck with yours.

Comment: Thanks! I have added another formula to check for blank cells.

Comment: That seems to work. Could you explain how it works? I don't understand how just using B2 seems to with

Comment: Imagine if you had =and(B2=$G2,B2<>"") as a regular formula in B2. If you pulled it across to the next cell, you would have =and(C2=$G2,C2<>""). If you pulled it down to the next row, you would have =and(D2=$G3,D2<>""). Conditional formatting formulas work the same way.

Comment: Mind blown... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**custom conditional formatting formula you are looking for:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN($G2:$G), {{IF(B2=$G2, 1)},
                               {IF(C2=$G2, 1)},
                               {IF(D2=$G2, 1)},
                               {IF(E2=$G2, 1)}}))
```

[image]

- **`ARRAYFORMULA`** is for overall continuity so the formula would not stop after evaluating 1st cell
- **`IF`** is obvious so we could nest some rules
- **`LEN`** checks range `G2:G` and handles the end of a calculation with the last non-empty cell
- **`{}`** these are called array brackets and ensure that what's inside them is taken as one piece
- **`},{`** comma between array brackets is able to stack these array pieces next to each other (imagine something like a virtual table constructed with 4 virtual columns - in this case)
- **`IF`** another one so we could evaluate something against something
- **`B2:$G2`** one of the 4 ranges (4 because you have 4 shops)
- **`$`** this is a lock for G column and makes sure that it looks always on the right column, otherwise, it would continue looking into H column from C column inputs, then I column for D column inputs etc.)
- **`1`** is equal to "true" eg. if given `IF` statement is calculable it returns kinda virtual agreement that given piece is calculated so formula could calculate for another `IF` chunk
- **`B2:E`** is the range where conditional format rule should apply. also because this range there is no need to add ranges like (like in usual cases when doing non-conditional formatting calculation) `B2:B`, `C2:C` etc. and instead you can use just `B2` and because this is conditional formatting formula everything else is handled simply by having conditional format formula - in other words: this whole formula works only as custom formula for conditional formatting (may also work in data validation) but it won't do the job if its pasted in some cell

Comment: Seems to do the trick. Any chance you could add some text explaining what each part of the rule/formula does? I'd like to understand so I can learn for future.

Comment: thanks, your solution works, but the accepted solution is much simpler.